# Cannot parse MTOM response

Tags: c#, wcf, mtom

I am utilizing a third party web service that is returning an object with a PDF attached using the MTOM encoding.

The object is structured as `Data[]` with each array element having fields `ContentType` and `Include`.

When I run the web service method, it completes the request fine, but it doesn't parse the response properly as the Include field gets parsed as `null`.

When I run Fiddler, I can actually see the remote web service returning a response with all the fields available.

This is what is sent in the SOAP:

```xml
<m:GetDocImageResponse>
    <x:data>
        <x:item xmime5:contentType="*/*">
        <xop:Include href="cid:id1"/></x:item>
    </x:data>
</m:GetDocImageResponse>
```

I see that `Include` has the property called `href` and this contains a reference to binary PDF document.

I am trying to parse the object according to WSDL:

```
Data[] retObject = null;
using (blahWS ws = new blahWS())
{
 try{
retObject = ws.GetDoc(parameters); //request completes with no errors, but `Include` is parse as null
[...]
   }
catch
{..}
 }
```

The web service reference is used with a simple `basicHttpBinding`

```xml
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHTTPwithMTOM" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" textEncoding="utf-8" />        
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Should I be parsing the response differently? Why is it not parsing the fields?

EDIT:

Full SOAP Response:

```xml
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: gSOAP/2.7
Content-Type: multipart/related; charset=utf-8; boundary="==nGpzR/KspN6ry7jG8CU4bonN2aujzfJamyN3xYjaldFXYpeUryNGb0UROC0B=="; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"; start-info="text/xml"
Content-Length: 180557
Connection: close

--==nGpzR/KspN6ry7jG8CU4bonN2aujzfJamyN3xYjaldFXYpeUryNGb0UROC0B==
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" xmlns:xmime5="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:m="http://www.mcleodsoftware.com/wsdl/ws4v.wsdl" xmlns:x="http://www.mcleodsoftware.com/schemas/ws4v.xsd">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <m:GetDocImageResponse>
        <x:data>
            <x:item xmime5:contentType="*/*">
                <xop:Include href="cid:id1"/></x:item>
        </x:data>
    </m:GetDocImageResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

```
--==nGpzR/KspN6ry7jG8CU4bonN2aujzfJamyN3xYjaldFXYpeUryNGb0UROC0B==
Content-Type: */*
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <id1>
...binary...
```

Data definition built using the WSDL provided:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mcleodsoftware.com/schemas/ws4v.xsd")]
public partial class Data : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private Include includeField;

    private string contentTypeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include", Order=0)]
    public Include Include {
        get {
            return this.includeField;
        }
        set {
            this.includeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Include");
        }
    }
```

Comment: if standard mtom is used then as long as you set message encoding to mtom no parsing is required by you, the attachment will be available in the response object

Comment: Can you provide the entire SOAP message (or better yet, the entire MIME message except for the encoded attachment?) Also, please provide the relevant ServiceContract / DataContract definitions. You need to make sure that the DataMember where you want MTOM decoding to happen is of type byte[].

Comment: @EugeneOsovetsky I added the SOAP response and object definiton. I don't have my own data contact, I was using the one built by WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your WSDL explicitly provides the schema for the  element. I'm pretty sure that's wrong and not standards-compliant. The  element should be declared to be simply of type xsd:base64Binary (e.g. see https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/GSOC/MTOM+Support+on+the+WSDL+Level ), and there are other standards-compliants ways to say in your WSDL that you're using MTOM (e.g. see http://www.w3.org/Submission/WS-MTOMPolicy/ )

If you fix your WSDL to be in compliance with standards (or at least with what WCF expects an "MTOM WSDL" to look like), I think everything should work. Actually, if you want to see what a proper "MTOM WSDL" looks like, just create a simple MTOM service code-first in WCF - e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395209.aspx - and look at the WSDL and XSD it produces.